# Regula Falsi method is throwing stack level too deep

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to implement the Falsi method for a given function.

Executing it with ruby Falsi.rb will throw `Falsi.rb:2: stack level too deep (SystemStackError)` . Which is very odd because I just implemented another algorithm using the same function and I didn't get this.

I tried to increase the stack limit using `ulimit -s 32768` (I saw this solution on another SO post) but this didn't do it either.

Here is my code:

```
def f(x)
    1/2 + 1/4 * (x**2) - x * Math.sin(x) - 1/2 * Math.cos(2*x)
end

def getRoot(a,b)

         c = (-(b-a) * f(b) + b * (f(b)-f(a)))/(f(b)-f(a))
         if(f(a) * f(b) < 0) then getRoot(a,c)
         else if(f(a) * f(b) > 0) then getRoot(c,b)
                else c
              end
         end
end


puts getRoot(-1000,-0.2)
```

using WolframAlpha a solution is -1.89 so the interval should be fine. Any ideas ?

Comment: You are talking about Regula Falsi? If yes, I'd edit the title because I've never seen it being called "falsi method".

Comment: sorry, in my country that's how it's called. Yes I am talking about Regula Falsi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, first things first, you're not writing the function you think you are.

```
1/2 + 1/4 * (x**2) - x * Math.sin(x) - 1/2 * Math.cos(2*x)
```

Don't write `1/2`, write `0.5` and so on and use parenthesis, this way ruby will know what you mean

```
0.5 + 0.25 * (x**2) - x * Math.sin(x) - 0.5* Math.cos(2*x)
```

That's the function you want to evaluate

Secondly, you're dealing with floating point numbers which are not exact, you'll probably never get to a situation where f(a)*f(b) = 0, you need to set a small interval in which you are fine with the answer. This should work:

```
def getRoot(a,b)
  c = (-(b-a) * f(b) + b * (f(b)-f(a)))/(f(b)-f(a))

  if(f(a) * f(b) < -0.00001) then 
    getRoot(a,c)
  elsif (f(a) * f(b) > 0.00001) then 
    getRoot(c,b)
  else 
    c
  end
end
```

I'm setting a small interval in which to accept the answer (0.00001) you can choose an even smaller one if you'd like.

Comment: ahhh the 0.00001 did the trick :P . You are indeed right mr hbejgel! Thank you!